# How to return a scrollable result set from getMetaData.getColumns()?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, resultset, database-metadata

I need to return a scrollable result set from the code below:

```
ResultSet columnMetaData = connection.getMetaData().getColumns(null, null, "my_table", "%");
```

However, the `getColumns()` API doesn't appear to provide a way for me to say what kind of result set type I'd like the `ResultSet` to be. It only returns a `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` result set. The only examples I've found for creating a scrollable result set involve creating a `Statement`. But I can only get a `DatabaseMetaData` object (and thereby call the `getColumns` method) from the `Connection` object, not a `Statement`.

Does anyone know of a way to return a scrollable result set from calling `getColumns()`?

By the way, the code above is used with xerial's SQLite JDBC Driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The JDBC specification explicitly specifies that metadata result sets need to be `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`. See [JDBC 4.3 Specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index3.html), section *7.5 SQL Objects and Their Attributes*:

> The `ResultSet` objects that are returned from a `DatabaseMetaData`
>   method have  a sensitivity of `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` and a concurrency of
>   `CONCUR_READ_ONLY`. `ResultSet.getHoldability` can be called to
>   determine the holdability of the returned `ResultSet` object as the
>   default holdability is implementation defined.

You don't explain why you need it to be scrollable, but you either need to transform it to a list, or maybe wrap it in a `CachedRowSet`.

Comment: I appreciate the help, Mark.  I'll try transforming the ResultSet into a list as you suggested.